# How capture keyboard events inside ViewChild

Tags: angular, typescript, dropdown, keyboard-events, viewchild

Using Angular 8 and Boostrap 4, I built a component and I am trying to capture keyboard events on the webpage. Inside the class I'm using @HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event']) and @ViewChild to associate buttoms' clicks and keyboard keys. My problem is when one element get focus, some commands stop working. I believe that the need to create @HostListener definitions for the element, but I'm not comprehending how to do that.

I get the element with this code:

`@ViewChild('btnChoose', {static: false}) btnChoose: any;`

And that is my @hostlistener definition:

```
  @HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
  keyEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if ((event.key === ' ') && (this.btnChoose)) {
      this.btnChoose.nativeElement.click();
    }
  }
```

The element is a dropdown, that is the HTML on template:

```
        <div class="btn-group dropup">
          <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
            aria-expanded="false" #btnChoose>
            Choose
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right options-menu m-0 p-0">
            <div *ngFor="let action of scene.getActionList()" class="button-container m-0 p-0"
              (click)="onActionSelected(action)">
              <button *ngIf="action.area == null "
                class="btn button-option {{action.cssClass}}">
                <!--dropdown-item -->
                {{ action | translateAction }}
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Other keys activate other buttons, but when the dropdown get focus, they stop working. I would like to be able to press one key like "Esc" to invoke function "this.btnChoose.nativeElement.blur();" and make other options accessible again.